# UICollectionViewCell translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property warning (iOS 16+, Xcode 14.2)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I am getting an odd compiler message when presenting a totally innocuous alert controller from a tableViewController:

```
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Add item", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
ac.addTextField()
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { _ in return }
ac.addAction(cancelAction)
present(ac, animated: true)
```

The message reads: "Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, and will result in incorrect self-sizing". I am puzzled, because I am not changing that property anywhere in my code. Also, I find it curious that tracing execution with the debugger shows that the message appears when the alert controller is presented, not when doing anything actually related to the table. This was not happening in Xcode 13. Where could that message be coming from? Can it be safely ignored? Thanks.

Comment: I've seen similar issues. It seems to be a UIAlertController bug that Apple needs to fix. It only seems to happen when adding a text field to the alert. I haven't had any problems just ignoring the issue. There's nothing you can change to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an internal layout error / warning message.

If you inspect the full message (it will look *like* this, with different object hex values for you):

```
[LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of a
UICollectionViewCell that is managed by a UICollectionView is not supported, 
and will result in incorrect self-sizing. 

View: <_UIAlertControllerTextFieldViewCollectionCell: 0x7f7a6ff1ba70; 
frame = (0 0; 270 24); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024fb0c0>; 
layer = <CALayer: 0x600002adb1c0>>
```

If you use `Debug View Hierarchy` and find that `View` you'll see that it is a collection view cell *inside the alert controller*:

[image]

You can safely ignore this message.

Comment: I suspected as much, but could not back it up with evidence, thank you. I find xCode 14 is littered with this kind of thing, lots of log noise, messages that leave you wondering if you did something wrong but end up being Apple internal issues, etc., etc.

Comment: @Torrontés This isn't an Xcode issue. It's an issue with iOS 16.

Comment: The net effect is the same.  Lots of wasted time.

Comment: I have just checked. This happens even if I target iOS 15.5.

Comment: @Torrontés - as much as we might wish, Apple engineers are not perfect. UIKit has many, many quirks - as well as many bugs.